# Codeigniter not_unique

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new with codeigniter and I am working with the form_validation of it. I found a function called is_unique which looks if the value is not already in the table. But is there an opposite of this function available? That checks if the value IS once in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't one. There are 2 alternatives:

1. Make your own callback rule.
2. If you have those values pre-fetched, use `is_array()` (native PHP functions can be used as rules).

Comment: @h2ooooooo We're talking about the CodeIgniter Form Validation library here, not general PHP code - it can't be used like that.

Comment: I see - I have no experience with the CI in general, so it was simply a guess.